# Socket connection failure when sending message between windows service and IIS AKKA.NET actor systems

Tags: akka.net

we are seeing following issue - we have couple of actor systems with actor instances - most of them are windows services - and exchange messages between them - this is generally working. We have now introduced new actor which is linked to API and therefore resides within IIS

this for some reason prevents messages to be delivered between windows service actor instance and remote actor which resides in IIS
using akka.net 1.1.1 and helios 2.1.3

the same actor code and config, when moved to another windows service does behave as expected

the IIS app is running and I can see netstat showing the port as listening and was even able to debug the code as far as socket being bound however under iis I get socket exception

```
*2016-08-23 10:02:44.232 +01:00 [Warning] Tried to associate with unreachable remote address ["akka.tcp://NodeSystem@127.0.0.1:7096"]. Address is now gated for 5000 ms, all messages to this address will be delivered to dead letters. Reason: ["Invalid address: akka.tcp://NodeSystem@127.0.0.1:7096"] "Caused by: [Akka.Remote.Transport.InvalidAssociationException: Association failure ---> Helios.Exceptions.HeliosConnectionException: failed as a result of System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Helios.Channels.ConnectException: LogError connecting to 127.0.0.1:7096 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
   at Helios.Channels.Sockets.SocketChannelAsyncOperation.Validate()
   at Helios.Channels.Sockets.TcpSocketChannel.DoFinishConnect(SocketChannelAsyncOperation operation)
   at Helios.Channels.Sockets.AbstractSocketChannel.AbstractSocketUnsafe.FinishConnect(SocketChannelAsyncOperation operation)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Helios.Channels.Bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.<DoResolveAndConnect>d__15.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at Akka.Remote.Transport.Helios.HeliosTcpTransport.<>c.<AssociateInternal>b__1_0(Task`1 tr)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Helios.Channels.ConnectException: LogError connecting to 127.0.0.1:7096 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
   at Helios.Channels.Sockets.SocketChannelAsyncOperation.Validate()
   at Helios.Channels.Sockets.TcpSocketChannel.DoFinishConnect(SocketChannelAsyncOperation operation)
   at Helios.Channels.Sockets.AbstractSocketChannel.AbstractSocketUnsafe.FinishConnect(SocketChannelAsyncOperation operation)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Helios.Channels.Bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.<DoResolveAndConnect>d__15.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at Akka.Remote.Transport.Helios.HeliosTcpTransport.<>c.<AssociateInternal>b__1_0(Task`1 tr)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Helios.Channels.ConnectException: LogError connecting to 127.0.0.1:7096 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
   at Helios.Channels.Sockets.SocketChannelAsyncOperation.Validate()
   at Helios.Channels.Sockets.TcpSocketChannel.DoFinishConnect(SocketChannelAsyncOperation operation)
   at Helios.Channels.Sockets.AbstractSocketChannel.AbstractSocketUnsafe.FinishConnect(SocketChannelAsyncOperation operation)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Helios.Channels.Bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.<DoResolveAndConnect>d__15.MoveNext()
---> (Inner Exception #0) Helios.Channels.ConnectException: LogError connecting to 127.0.0.1:7096 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
   at Helios.Channels.Sockets.SocketChannelAsyncOperation.Validate()
   at Helios.Channels.Sockets.TcpSocketChannel.DoFinishConnect(SocketChannelAsyncOperation operation)
   at Helios.Channels.Sockets.AbstractSocketChannel.AbstractSocketUnsafe.FinishConnect(SocketChannelAsyncOperation operation)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---<---
<---
<---
 ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Helios.Channels.ConnectException: LogError connecting to 127.0.0.1:7096 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
   at Helios.Channels.Sockets.SocketChannelAsyncOperation.Validate()
   at Helios.Channels.Sockets.TcpSocketChannel.DoFinishConnect(SocketChannelAsyncOperation operation)
   at Helios.Channels.Sockets.AbstractSocketChannel.AbstractSocketUnsafe.FinishConnect(SocketChannelAsyncOperation operation)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Helios.Channels.Bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.<DoResolveAndConnect>d__15.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at Akka.Remote.Transport.Helios.HeliosTcpTransport.<>c.<AssociateInternal>b__1_0(Task`1 tr)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Akka.Remote.Transport.Helios.HeliosTcpTransport.<>c.<AssociateInternal>b__1_1(Task`1 r)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Akka.Remote.Transport.Helios.HeliosTransport.<Associate>d__27.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---]"
2016-08-23 10:02:44.233 +01:00 [Error] "Invalid address: akka.tcp://NodeSystem@127.0.0.1:7096"
Akka.Remote.InvalidAssociation: Invalid address: akka.tcp://NodeSystem@127.0.0.1:7096 ---> Akka.Remote.Transport.InvalidAssociationException: Association failure ---> Helios.Exceptions.HeliosConnectionException: failed as a result of System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Helios.Channels.ConnectException: LogError connecting to 127.0.0.1:7096 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
   at Helios.Channels.Sockets.SocketChannelAsyncOperation.Validate()
   at Helios.Channels.Sockets.TcpSocketChannel.DoFinishConnect(SocketChannelAsyncOperation operation)
   at Helios.Channels.Sockets.AbstractSocketChannel.AbstractSocketUnsafe.FinishConnect(SocketChannelAsyncOperation operation)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Helios.Channels.Bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.<DoResolveAndConnect>d__15.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at Akka.Remote.Transport.Helios.HeliosTcpTransport.<>c.<AssociateInternal>b__1_0(Task`1 tr)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Helios.Channels.ConnectException: LogError connecting to 127.0.0.1:7096 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
   at Helios.Channels.Sockets.SocketChannelAsyncOperation.Validate()
   at Helios.Channels.Sockets.TcpSocketChannel.DoFinishConnect(SocketChannelAsyncOperation operation)
   at Helios.Channels.Sockets.AbstractSocketChannel.AbstractSocketUnsafe.FinishConnect(SocketChannelAsyncOperation operation)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Helios.Channels.Bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.<DoResolveAndConnect>d__15.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at Akka.Remote.Transport.Helios.HeliosTcpTransport.<>c.<AssociateInternal>b__1_0(Task`1 tr)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Helios.Channels.ConnectException: LogError connecting to 127.0.0.1:7096 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
   at Helios.Channels.Sockets.SocketChannelAsyncOperation.Validate()
   at Helios.Channels.Sockets.TcpSocketChannel.DoFinishConnect(SocketChannelAsyncOperation operation)
   at Helios.Channels.Sockets.AbstractSocketChannel.AbstractSocketUnsafe.FinishConnect(SocketChannelAsyncOperation operation)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Helios.Channels.Bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.<DoResolveAndConnect>d__15.MoveNext()
---> (Inner Exception #0) Helios.Channels.ConnectException: LogError connecting to 127.0.0.1:7096 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
   at Helios.Channels.Sockets.SocketChannelAsyncOperation.Validate()
   at Helios.Channels.Sockets.TcpSocketChannel.DoFinishConnect(SocketChannelAsyncOperation operation)
   at Helios.Channels.Sockets.AbstractSocketChannel.AbstractSocketUnsafe.FinishConnect(SocketChannelAsyncOperation operation)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---<---
<---
<---
 ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Helios.Channels.ConnectException: LogError connecting to 127.0.0.1:7096 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
   at Helios.Channels.Sockets.SocketChannelAsyncOperation.Validate()
   at Helios.Channels.Sockets.TcpSocketChannel.DoFinishConnect(SocketChannelAsyncOperation operation)
   at Helios.Channels.Sockets.AbstractSocketChannel.AbstractSocketUnsafe.FinishConnect(SocketChannelAsyncOperation operation)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Helios.Channels.Bootstrap.ClientBootstrap.<DoResolveAndConnect>d__15.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at Akka.Remote.Transport.Helios.HeliosTcpTransport.<>c.<AssociateInternal>b__1_0(Task`1 tr)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Akka.Remote.Transport.Helios.HeliosTcpTransport.<>c.<AssociateInternal>b__1_1(Task`1 r)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Akka.Remote.Transport.Helios.HeliosTransport.<Associate>d__27.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Akka.Remote.EndpointWriter.PublishAndThrow(Exception reason, LogLevel level)
   at Akka.Remote.EndpointWriter.<Initializing>b__24_1(Failure failure)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Action`1 , Action`1 , Action`1 )
   at Akka.Tools.MatchHandler.PartialHandlerArgumentsCapture`4.Handle(T value)
   at Akka.Actor.ReceiveActor.ExecutePartialMessageHandler(Object message, PartialAction`1 partialAction)
   at Akka.Actor.ReceiveActor.OnReceive(Object message)
   at Akka.Actor.UntypedActor.Receive(Object message)
   at Akka.Actor.ActorBase.AroundReceive(Receive receive, Object message)
   at Akka.Actor.ActorCell.ReceiveMessage(Object message)
   at Akka.Actor.ActorCell.Invoke(Envelope envelope)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Akka.Actor.ActorCell.HandleFailed(Failed f)
   at Akka.Actor.ActorCell.SysMsgInvokeAll(EarliestFirstSystemMessageList messages, Int32 currentState)*
```

this is the hocon for the sending actor

```
akka {
            # here we are configuring log levels
            log-config-on-start = on
            stdout-loglevel = INFO
            loglevel = DEBUG
            loggers = ["Akka.Logger.Serilog.SerilogLogger, Akka.Logger.Serilog"]
             persistence
            {
             journal 
             {
              plugin = "akka.persistence.journal.sql-server"

                sql-server 
                {
                  # qualified type name of the SQL Server persistence journal actor
                  class = "Akka.Persistence.SqlServer.Journal.SqlServerJournal, Akka.Persistence.SqlServer"

                  # dispatcher used to drive journal actor
                  plugin-dispatcher = "akka.actor.default-dispatcher"

                  # connection string used for database access
                  connection-string = "Data Source=wcamm0q3pdbd1.gbcaydc.emea.bankofamerica.com,15001;Initial Catalog=BrokerDealer;User ID=BDLFUser;Password=dfnklgkdfkg"

                  # default SQL commands timeout
                  connection-timeout = 30s

                  # SQL server schema name to table corresponding with persistent journal
                  schema-name = dbo

                  # SQL server table corresponding with persistent journal
                  table-name = AKKAJournal

                  # should corresponding journal table be initialized automatically
                  auto-initialize = off

                  # timestamp provider used for generation of journal entries timestamps
                  timestamp-provider = "Akka.Persistence.Sql.Common.Journal.DefaultTimestampProvider, Akka.Persistence.Sql.Common"

                  # metadata table
                  metadata-table-name = AKKAMetadata
                }
             }
             snapshot-store 
             {
               plugin = "akka.persistence.snapshot-store.sql-server"

                sql-server 
                {

                    # qualified type name of the SQL Server persistence journal actor
                    class = "Akka.Persistence.SqlServer.Snapshot.SqlServerSnapshotStore, Akka.Persistence.SqlServer"

                    # dispatcher used to drive journal actor
                    plugin-dispatcher = "akka.actor.default-dispatcher"

                    # connection string used for database access
                    connection-string = "Data Source=wcamm0q3pdbd1.gbcaydc.emea.bankofamerica.com,15001;Initial Catalog=BrokerDealer;User ID=BDLFUser;Password=dfgdfgdfg"

                    # default SQL commands timeout
                    connection-timeout = 30s

                    # SQL server schema name to table corresponding with persistent journal
                    schema-name = dbo

                    # SQL server table corresponding with persistent journal
                    table-name = AKKASnapshot

                    # should corresponding journal table be initialized automatically
                    auto-initialize = off
                }
             }
          }
            # this config section will be referenced as akka.actor
            actor {
              provider = "Akka.Remote.RemoteActorRefProvider, Akka.Remote"
              debug {
                  receive = on
                  autoreceive = on
                  lifecycle = on
                  event-stream = on
                  unhandled = on
              }
              deployment {
              /CashFundingManagementView {
                router = smallest-mailbox-pool
                nr-of-instances = 1
                }
              }
            }
            # here we're configuring the Akka.Remote module
            remote {
              helios.tcp {
                  transport-class =
            "Akka.Remote.Transport.Helios.HeliosTcpTransport, Akka.Remote"
                  #applied-adapters = []
                  transport-protocol = tcp
                  port = 7095
                  hostname = "localhost"
              }
            log-remote-lifecycle-events = INFO           
          }
```

this is the destination actor path we use

akka.tcp://NodeSystem@127.0.0.1:7096/user/FundingManagementView

and the destination HOCON

```
 akka {
          loglevel = DEBUG
          log-config-on-start = on    
          loggers = ["Akka.Logger.Serilog.SerilogLogger, Akka.Logger.Serilog"]

          persistence {
        snapshot-store {

            # Path to the snapshot store plugin to be used
            plugin = "akka.persistence.snapshot-store.local"

            # Local filesystem snapshot store plugin.
            local {

                # Class name of the plugin.
                class = "Akka.Persistence.Snapshot.LocalSnapshotStore, Akka.Persistence"

                # Dispatcher for the plugin actor.
                plugin-dispatcher = "akka.persistence.dispatchers.default-plugin-dispatcher"

                # Dispatcher for streaming snapshot IO.
                stream-dispatcher = "akka.persistence.dispatchers.default-stream-dispatcher"

                # Storage location of snapshot files.
                dir = "c:/logs"
            }
        }
    }

          actor {
            provider = "Akka.Remote.RemoteActorRefProvider, Akka.Remote"
            debug {
              receive = on
              autoreceive = on
              lifecycle = on
              event-stream = on
              unhandled = on
            }
            deployment 
            {
              /FundingManagementView
              {                
                router = smallest-mailbox-pool
                nr-of-instances = 1               
              }
              /RealtimeControllerService
              {                
                router = smallest-mailbox-pool
                nr-of-instances = 1               
              }
              /SignalRBridge
              {                
                router = smallest-mailbox-pool
                nr-of-instances = 1               
              }
            }   
          }

          remote {
              helios.tcp {
                  transport-class = "Akka.Remote.Transport.Helios.HeliosTcpTransport, Akka.Remote"
                  transport-protocol = tcp
                  port = 7096
                  hostname = 0.0.0.0 # listen on all interfaces
                  public-hostname = "localhost"
              }
          }
        }
```

any ideas as to diagnostics, I am currently trying to debug through the association workflow but it will take time...

the OS here is fairly locked down so I wonder if this is caused by some permission issue but still wonder why it inherently works win. service to win. service and not win.servie to IIS (Express) actor system

Any help greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

the same code/config is working on my colleague's box - sounds like my box is funny - I can telnet to the socket occassionally but more often than not, it stops listening